# dev_appserver.py is not reloading changed code

Tags: python, google-app-engine

At some point in the last few months, dev_appserver.py completely stopped reloading changed code on my Google App Engine project. Unfortunately, because the gap in my development coincided with at least one version change in the appserver platform, I can't be more specific about exactly when the symptom began.

Manually stopping and starting dev_appserver.py does cause changes to be reflected immediately, but the old behavior was quite useful and I am eager to make it work again.

I have found some code in the appengine source (`_internal/django/utils/autoreload.py`) which appears to be responsible for the reloading behavior, so I suspect that this is a bug and not an intended functionality change. The reloading code looks fairly straightforward and does not appear to depend on any fancy notification facilities in the OS, so I don't think that it is an OS bug. I'm running on MacOS 10.8.2 and Python 2.7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack Overflow is the official venue for App Engine technical questions, but this sounds more like a bug report. Bug reports are best sent to the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list).

Comment: Thank you; it is now [there](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8383). I'll leave this here for a while though, in case anyone enterprising wants to tackle it directly....